# Evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, theta-functions

I would like to evaluate the following summation 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}
\end{equation} 
assuming  $ 0<q<1$ obviously the series converge but can anyone help me how to evaluate it?
I know it's related to Jacobi theta function fro some special value but that is not what I'm looking for as an answer.

Comment: If you don't wand a "Theta" answer, what then ? What do you mean by "evaluate" ?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by refusal to accept the Jacobi theta function as the (correct) answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean I'm looking for an approximation of the series, some analytical way to approximate where the series converges.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Jacobi [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) has a section on "Jacobi identities" that has an equation that you may be looking for. The problem is that as $q\to 1$ the infinite sum approaches its limit very slowly. The identity essentially relates it to theta evaluated at a much smaller value of $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost there: the Jacobi's third theta function in nome form is
$$
\vartheta_3(\eta, q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2} \eta^n.
$$
Thus your series can be evaluated via $\frac{1}{2}(\vartheta_3(1,q)-1)$. Most scientific computing packages allow you to do so. For example, below is the plot of the series against $0<q<1$ using the [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/elliptic.html#jacobi-elliptic-functions) package (note $\vartheta_3(1,q)$ corresponds to `mpmath.jtheta(n=3, z=0, q=q)`.)

[[image: Summation when <span class=]$0<q<1$, $q\in\mathbb{R}$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0vzZ.png)

**EDIT: Minimax Rational Approximation**

We will write $\vartheta_3(q)$ for $\vartheta_3(1,q)$. As OP asked for analytical approximation when $q\in\mathbb{R}$ with small values, it might be possible to consider as simple as a rational function of the form
$$
r(q) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i q^i}{1 + \sum_{i=1}^m b_i q^i}.
$$
Note that $r(q)$ is quasi-convex, and thus we can generate a bunch of evaluations $\{(q_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ with $y_i=\vartheta_3(q_i)$ and 
do a minimax rational fit (c.f. [Boyd Ex. A 5.2](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook_extra_exercises.pdf)) to minimize the max of $\lvert{r(q_i) - \vartheta_i(q_i)}\rvert$.
For example, using $N=1000$ and $n=m=3$ we obtained a fit
$$
\hat{\mathbf{a}} = {[
   1.044359498, \quad
   -1.271249380, \quad
   -0.44275578, \quad
   0.670133658
]}^{\top}, \quad
\hat{\mathbf{b}} = {[
  -2.56134660,\quad
  2.129914536,\quad
  -0.568564211
]}^{\top}
$$
The maximum absolute error is below $0.05$ for $q$ bounded below from $1$, and well below $0.05$ for most of the values (see below). It should be feasible to study bounds on the derivate of $\vartheta_3(q)$ with small values of $q$, hence the error bound can be made uniform in that region.
And certainly you can use more samples and finer stopping criteria to meet your accuracy need.

[[image: Abs error of minimax fit with <span class=]$m=n=3$.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfGrJ.png)

Comment: With the given definition the correct answer should involve $\vartheta_3(\color{red}1,q)$.

Comment: @user, thank you! I've fixed the typo

Comment: @JiayaoZhang this is nice form but I'm actually looking for a more analytical way to approximate the series rather than using scientific computing packages.

Comment: @Jason, I'm not sure if there's an analytical approximation; but if you don't care too much about the behaviour as $q \to 1$ and are only interested in the case where $q\in\mathbb{R}$, it seems even rational function of a low degree can do the job just fine (something like relative error $\lesssim 0.1$, which can be found using cvx).

Comment: @JiayaoZhang actually in my case q is way too smaller than 1 and of course is of real values, however, I didn't get what you mean, can you explain it a little more? or tell me where to look?

Comment: I have an impression that your first figure shows $\vartheta_3(1,q)$ instead of the claimed function.

Comment: @user Figure plots `(mpmath.jtheta(3, 0, q)-1)/2`, which I think should be the OP series. It was indeed bogus though, thanks! I forgot to subtract 1 and divide by 2. Fig 2 is ok.